# send_with_components() got an unexpected keyword argument 'ephemeral'

Tags: python, discord.py

```
m = await interaction.channel.send(f'<@{interaction.author.id}>',embed=embed, components=[Button(label='News', custom_id="button-give-news", style=ButtonStyle.grey),Button(label='Media', custom_id="button-give-media", style=ButtonStyle.red)], ephemeral=True)
```

I tryed to send ephemeral message with Buttons, but Python send Error.

```
send_with_components() got an unexpected keyword argument 'ephemeral'
```

What i need to do ?

Comment: I don't see where you've used `send_with_components`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a message to be ephemeral, it has to directly reply to the user. If you're sending into a specific channel, that means it's not directly replying to the user. To get around this, you can just switch `interaction.channel.send` to `interaction.response.send_message()`

Unfortunately, that means that what you're going for (which I assume is to respond ephemerally in another channel) is not possible.